# Permission denied in XCode debugging run

Tags: swift, xcode, file-io, permissions

I want to read all files in a folder:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let directoryEnumerator = fileManager.enumerator(at: self.url,
                                                 includingPropertiesForKeys: resourceKeys,
                                                 options: skipHiddenFiles ? [.skipsHiddenFiles] : [],
                                                 errorHandler: { (url, error) -> Bool in
                                                    print("directoryEnumerator error at \(url): ", error)
                                                    accessError = true
                                                    return true
})!
```

In that folder there are two files. But I get an Error, that I have not the permission to do this (to read it):

> directoryEnumerator error at
> file:///Users/Shared/MeinDesktop/fasttemp/tmp/src:  Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “src” couldn’t be opened
> because you don’t have permission to view it."
> UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/Shared/MeinDesktop/fasttemp/tmp/src,
> NSFilePath=/Users/Shared/MeinDesktop/fasttemp/tmp/src,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x600000a94240 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
> Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

I added Xcode itself as well as the generated app file to security section with full access. Nothing changed! The code worked for years, so I don't believe that this is wrong. Do I need some settings in XCode?

Comment: Is your app sandboxed?

Comment: Oh, were can I check it? I simply created a new project and let all settings untouched.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:
There is a file in the project named "YourProjectName.entitlements".
Within that file there is a option to sandbox the app. Set this to "NO" and it works fine! *Hurray*